# Interactive Flowchart Like Code Map When Debugging JavaScript (in Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, code-map, code-visualization

[image]

When reading some big open source projects' codes, it'd be pleasant if there's a view that shows the visualization result of program executing flow when debugging JavaScript. So if there're any tools like code map for debugging javascript? Like this: https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-code-map-can-be-used-to-visualize-the-call-stacks-directly